# Dropping the first column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
    command             description
0   aaa ikegroup WORD   Name of the IKE group
1   aaa ikegroup <cr>   
0   aaa locald trace    Show trace data for the locald component(cisco...
0   aaa login trace Show trace data for login sub system
0   aaa password-policy statistics  Show statistics related to password policy
1   aaa password-policy WORD    Name of the Password Policy
```

Above is how my dataframe looks like.
I want to get rid of the very first column which has numbers, not the `command` column. However, when I do this:

`df2 = df.drop([df.columns[0]], axis='columns')`

This drops the `command` column, not the ones with the index.

How can I drop the first one?

Comment: The first column is just your index

Comment: It follows when I export it to a `csv`. I don't want that

Comment: `df.to_csv('name_of_file.csv', index=False)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, your first column is just your index. You can always hide in your notebook it with

```
df.style.hide_index()
```

but not sure if that brings much value.

If you're writing to a file (e.g. `to_csv`), you can always set `index=False` to ignore it, like

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Also might be worth mentioning setting the index to the first column, instead of just hiding it

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign any column as index:

```
df.set_index('command', inplace=True)
```

Other useful commands:

```
# reset the index
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

# sort by index
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```